# How to use a custom matcher when using toHaveBeenCalledWith in jasmine test?

Tags: angular, post, jasmine, matcher, angular-httpclient

The following test-case verifies if the **service** (which uses **Angular HttpClient** to do a post request) does indeed use certain headers.

I want to write some custom matching code to check if the headers contains a certain key and value, like:

```
headers.get('Session') === 'abc'
```

My question is what to write at the `???` in below example?

```js
spyOn(http, 'post').and.returnValue(new Observable<Response>());

const result = service.Post<string>(data);

assert.isNotNull(result);

expect(http.post).toHaveBeenCalledWith(`http://localhost/odata/Employees`, jasmine.any(String),
    {
        headers: // ???,
        observe: 'response'
    });
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

I created this this matcher class:

```js
class HttpHeadersMatcher {

    constructor(private check: { [name: string]: string }) {
    }

    public asymmetricMatch(options: any): boolean {
        const headers: HttpHeaders = options.headers;

        assert.equal(options.observe, 'response');

        Object.keys(this.check)
            .forEach((key: string) => {
                assert.equal(headers.get(key), this.check[key], `The header '${key}' does not have the correct value`);
            });

        return true;
    }

    public jasmineToString(): string {
        return `<HeaderMatching: ${JSON.stringify(this.check)}>`;
    }
}
```

Which is used like:

```js
expect(http.post).toHaveBeenCalledWith(`http://localhost/odata/Employees`, jasmine.any(String), new HttpHeadersMatcher({ 'Session': 'abc' }));
```

My project and example test code can also be found here: [angular-odata-es5 : angularODataService.spec.ts](https://github.com/StefH/angular-odata-es5/blob/master/test/angularODataService.spec.ts#L13)